# passing data-set as parameter in url ssrs

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters

i'm trying to use the action option from a cell in a table(text box properties).
the action supposed to open a report from a URL. 
this report gets 2 parameters: case_input ( the case_id in the cell, i get it from the data set), and id_pat (null).
i tried this link:

http:///Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fKpiReports%2freport_bill_patient_oneTbl&ViewMode=Detail&case_input=(Fields!id_case.Value)&id_pat_input:isnull=true

but when the report opened i didn't get the value of id_case.
any ideas?
thank you...:)

Comment: try print this URL in separate column "in textbox" & see whether its concatenating correctly or not

Comment: i put textbox for the parameter-case_input, but i see "case+input" and not the case number..

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the report you are trying to open using the URL is set to accept a null value for the id parameter.

Comment: yes, the report parameter can get null. it works when i open it without the url.. i think that the problem is with case_input